# Modify vim's 't{char}' to have cursor land on {char}

Tags: vim

In standard vim, when you hit t{char} in normal mode, the cursor is moved to the space before the next instance of {char} to the right. Similarly, T{char} moves the cursor to the space after the next instance of {char} to the left.

Is there a way to set this so that t{char} (or T{char}) moves the cursor ON TOP OF the next instance/previous instance of {char}?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `f{char}` and `F{char}`. See [`:help f`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#f).